# meta box plugin use php array as select options?

Tags: php, wordpress, html-select, meta-boxes

I have PHP array

```
$my_array=Array
(
  [0] => standard
  [1] =>  aside
  [2] =>  image
  [3] =>  gallery
  [4] =>  video
  [5] =>  status
  [6] =>  quote
  [7] =>  link
  [8] =>  chat
  [9] =>  audio
 );
```

I want to use it as meta-box plugin select options

```
 array(
    'name' =>  __( 'Select', 'rwmb' ),
    'id'   => "{$prefix}page_icon",
    'type'     => 'select',
    'options'  => $my_array,
    'multiple'    => false,
    'placeholder' => __( 'Select an Item', 'rwmb' ),
 ),
```

It give me error.

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in plugins\meta-box\inc\fields\select.php on line 132

how I can use it?
any solution accepted.
thanks.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in \plugins\meta-box\inc\fields\select.php on line 132

Comment: are you actually passing the array like you have written above?

Comment: yes same in the code.

Comment: I wonder if this would suit your purposes more closely? `add_theme_support( 'post-formats',
 array(
  'gallery',
  'image',
  'quote',
  'video',
  'audio',
                // etc...
 )
);`

Comment: Relevant link here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See where you declare array

it's may be out of function

or inside of other function

try to declare it in function or make array global

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
    // SELECT BOX
    array(
        'name'     => __( 'Select', 'rwmb' ),
        'id'       => "{$prefix}select",
        'type'     => 'select',
        // Array of 'value' => 'Label' pairs for select box
        'options'  => array(
            'standard' => __( 'Standard', 'rwmb' ),
            'aside'    => __( 'Aside',    'rwmb' ),
            'gallery'  => __( 'Gallery',  'rwmb' ),
            'image'    => __( 'image',    'rwmb' ),
            'aside'    => __( 'Aside',    'rwmb' ),
            'video'    => __( 'Video',    'rwmb' ),
            'status'   => __( 'Status',   'rwmb' ),
            'quote'    => __( 'Quote',    'rwmb' ),
            'link'     => __( 'Link',     'rwmb' ),
            'chat'     => __( 'Chat',     'rwmb' ),
            'audio'    => __( 'Audio',    'rwmb' ),
        ),
        // Select multiple values, optional. Default is false.
        'multiple'    => FALSE,
        'std'         => 'standard',
        'placeholder' => __( 'Select an Item', 'rwmb' ),
    ),
```

Your array is not written in the correct PHP syntax, so that's most likely the error you're receiving.

There's a nice explanation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in the PHP manual on how to construct arrays .

But you should also consider the `add_theme_support()` advice suggested in the comments, if you're setting up multiple post formats.

It will give a radio box like this one.

[image: Post formats]

See for example this [description](http://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/post-formats/).

Comment: yes this what I already tried and it works also,
but that array I fetching manually and it has minimum 100 of elements so, this way is not useful to me,
by the way thanks ...

Comment: Is any way to set 'placeholder' value as a 'std' value ?

Answer (score 0):

Its not logical error, its from your syntax.
Check your syntax from foreach.